# Scraping from one URL to another URL in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

My question is in regards to R being able to read a URL link. The example that I use is solely for illustration purposes. Say that I have the following webpage that I want to read (chosen at random);

https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/faculty

It has a list of professor names with a URL link, I am trying to build a script which can read a webpage similar to this for instance and access each URL link and make a search for certain keywords regarding their publications.

I currently have my script to scan an individual website for certain keywords which I post below.

```
 library(rvest)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(stringr)

    prof <- readLines("https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/faculty/jsadams")

    library(dplyr)
    text_df <- data_frame(text = prof) 

    text_df <- as.data.frame.table(text_df)


    keywords <- c("nonskeletal", "antimicrobial response")
    text_df %>%
      filter(str_detect(text, keywords[1]) | str_detect(text, keywords[2]))
```

This should return publications 1, 2 and 4 under the section "Selected Publications" on the professors webpage.

Now I am trying to get R to read each professors page from the faculty link (https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/faculty) and see if each professor has publications with the keywords listed above.

1. Read: https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/faculty
2. Access each link and read each faculty member page:
3. Return if value "keywords" = TRUE:
4. List professors publications or text that has the "keywords" in:

I have already been able to do this for each individual page but I would perhaps prefer a loop or function so I do not have to copy and paste each professors page URL each time.

*Just a slight disclaimer - I have no connection with the UCLA or the professor on that website, the professor URL I chose just so happened to be the first professor listed on the faculty of professors webpage.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this as follows. This is "quick and dirty" code, but hopefully provides a basis for something better.

First, you need the correct selectors to get the faculty names and the links to their pages. Create a data frame with that information:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(tidytext)

page <- read_html("https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu/faculty")
table1 <- page %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "///table[1]/tr/td/a")
names <- table1 %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)
links <- table1 %>% 
  html_attrs() %>% 
  unlist(use.names = FALSE)

data1  <- data.frame(name = names, href = links)
head(data1)

               name              href
1        John Adams  /faculty/jsadams
2    Utpal Banerjee /faculty/banerjee
3 Siobhan Braybrook /faculty/siobhanb
4     Jau-Nian Chen   /faculty/chenjn
5     Amander Clark   /faculty/clarka
6       Daniel Cohn    /faculty/dcohn
```

Next, you need a function that takes the values in the `href` column, fetches the staff page and looks for keywords. I took a different approach to you, using `tidytext` to break all of the publications down into individual words, then counting rows where any of the keywords occur. This means that "antimicrobial response" has to be two separate words, so you may want to do that differently.

The function returns a count which is > 0 if any of the keywords were present.

```
get_pubs <- function(href) {
  page <- read_html(paste0("https://www.mcdb.ucla.edu", href))
  pubs <- data.frame(text = page %>% 
                              html_nodes("div.mcdb-faculty-pubs p") %>%
                              html_text(),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pubs <- pubs %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, text)
pubs %>% 
  filter(word %in% c("nonskeletal", "antimicrobial", "response")) %>% 
  nrow()
}
```

Now you can apply the function to each `href`:

```
data1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(count = sapply(href, function(x) get_pubs(x)))
```

Which faculty had at least one keyword in their publications?

```
data1 %>%
  filter(count > 0)

               name               href count
1        John Adams   /faculty/jsadams     9
2         Arjun Deb      /faculty/adeb     1
3     Tracy Johnson /faculty/tljohnson     1
4       Chentao Lin      /faculty/clin     1
5      Jeffrey Long /faculty/jeffalong     1
6 Matteo Pellegrini   /faculty/matteop     1
```